# bayesian curve fitting

Tags: machine-learning, probability, bayesian

On Bishop's Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning book, equation 1.68 says

$p(t|x,X,T) =  \int p(t|x,w) p(w|X,T) dw$

Here t is the target value, (X,T) is training dataset. I do now understand how the RHS came from LHS. Intuitively it makes sense. My confusion is from $p(t|x,X,T) =  \int p(t|x,w,X,T) dw$, should not RHS be $\int p(t|x,w) p(w)$? I know $w$ is dependent on $X$ and $T$, we have to estimate $w$ from training data. But how it came mathematically?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability#Applications

Comment: The formula is correct if $t$ is independent from $X,T$ conditional on $x,w$ (using the confusing symbols in the equation).

Comment: @whuber, thanks for your comment. could you please answer my updated question?

Comment: The Wikipedia link answers the updated question too.

Answer (score 3):

The predictive distribution $p(t|x,X,T)$ is the marginal distribution of
$p(t|x,w) p(w|X,T) $.

The [Marginal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution) is givne as:

$
p_U(u) = \int_y p_{U,V}(u,v) \, \mathrm{d}v = \int_v p_{U\mid V}(u\mid v) \, p_V(v) \, \mathrm{d}v   (1)
$

Using [Conditional probability rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability) you can show that

$p(t|x,w) p(w|X,T)=p(t,w|x,X,T) (2)$

Comparing (1) and (2) we see the correspondence $t=u$ and $w=v$

$p(t|x,X,T)= \int p(t,w|x,X,T)  dw$